# Restricting child view within parent boundries

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a rectangular box and putting an imageView inside it which can be moved. While doing onMove I noticed that imageView is going out of boundries of it's parent view which I don't want. I want to restrict the imageView within the boundaries of it's parent view. How to do that.

Here is the xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/objContainer"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_default" />
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And code to handletouch event:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            final float x = event.getRawX();
            final float y = event.getRawY();

            // Remember where we started
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


            final float x1 = event.getRawX();
            final float y1 = event.getRawY();

            // Calculate the distance moved
            final float dx = x1 - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y1 - mLastTouchY;

            // Move the object
            mPosX += dx;
            mPosY += dy;
            view.setX(mPosX);
            view.setY(mPosY);

            // Remember this touch position for the next move event
            mLastTouchX = x1;
            mLastTouchY = y1;

            // Invalidate to request a redraw
            root.invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}}
```

Comment: what is mPosX in this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside of your overridden `onTouch` you need to check if the following move will keep the `ImageView` inside its container.

In other words you need to check if `ImageView`'s rectangle will stay inside the parent after being moved by dx, dy.

Here's an example:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    ...
    // Calculate the distance moved
    final float dx = x1 - mLastTouchX;
    final float dy = y1 - mLastTouchY;

    // Make sure we will still be the in parent's container
    Rect parent = new Rect(0, 0, root.getWidth(), root.getHeight());

    int newLeft = (int) (iv.getX() + dx),
            newTop = (int) (iv.getY() + dy),
            newRight = newLeft + iv.getWidth(),
            newBottom = newTop + iv.getHeight();

    if (!parent.contains(newLeft, newTop, newRight, newBottom)) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("OOB @ %d, %d - %d, %d",
                newLeft, newTop, newRight, newBottom));
        break;
    }
    ...
```

Note also that you don't need to invalidate the container, as setX/setY invalidates the `ImageView` itself.

Comment: can you tell for id we want to be able to drag a view inside boundaries, such that as soon as parent and child view boundaries match it shouldn't move.